# "take a picture and present it" in portrait mode on Samsung Galaxy S

Tags: android, android-intent, galaxy

I am trying to simply take a picture and present it in an ImageView with my samsung galaxy s. it's working fine when I do it on landscape but **not** on portrait. I am not getting any error or exception - just not getting anything... There is a lot of questions about this topic and it seems to be problematic (something about camera orientation) but counldn't figure out the final solution for a simple "take a picture and present it" code.
here is my (problematic) code that doesn't work:

```
private void setUpListeners() {
    takePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
            Log.d("onActivityResult", "CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST returned");
            dishImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            if (dishImage==null)
                Log.d("onActivityResult", "dishImage==null");
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dishinfodishimageview);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(dishImage);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            takePicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            (new UploadImage()).execute(null);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("onActivityResult",
                "no able to presenting the picture of the dish");
    }
```

}

I just need a code that works (on any device) or a fix to my code...
thx.

Comment: see this old [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11084765/1250370). It might help you. :)

Comment: for rotate your bitmap image refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6051340/1250370)

Comment: I still don't get it :in portrait orientation I don't get a rotated picture...I don't get a picture at all...and not an error or exception...its seems that its skipping the line imageView.setImageBitmap(dishImage);(but in landscape it's working...)

Comment: found the problem - for some reason when the picture is taken in a landscape when resuming to the activity, the onCreate isn't being called. **However, when taken a picture in a portrait orientation , the onCreate function is called and reset the activity variables** and therefore I didn't saw the taken picture... do someone know the reason for this behavior ?

Comment: has anyone found a solution in this weird behaviour?? I am having the same troubles and... I am stack overflow!!

Comment: This should help!

[See this, as how I used to fix the orientation issue][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16742014/583344

Comment: Visit here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450539/images-taken-with-action-image-capture-always-returns-1-for-exifinterface-tag-or>. The guy has represented a complete solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that `onCreate()` is called is because when you do call the camera activity during the portrait orientation, it will change the orientation and destroy your previous activity. After finishing the `onActivityResult()`, your activity will be re-created.

One solution to this problem is to set the manifest to ignore changes on orientation change, you can do it by using this:

```
<activity android:name=".MyMainActivity"
     android:configChanges="orientation"
     android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

If you are using API starts with level 13, you can consider `screenSize` for the configChanges manifest.

Answer (score 1):

I can only suggest a hack for this problem. Save your results in shared preferences in `onActivityResult()` and during `onCreate` load your content from shared preferences. I know this is a bad solution but this will keep you going until you find a better answer. And don't forget to clear your shared preferences once you are done, else your activity will always initialize with old data.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code.. it worked for me with Samsung galaxy S2 Insert the Following Code in onActivityResult()

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(cameraimagename);
                    String orientString = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
                    int orientation = orientString != null ? Integer.parseInt(orientString) : ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
                    int rotationAngle = 0;
                    System.out.println("orientation is : "+orientation);
                    System.out.println("ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 : "+ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90);
                    System.out.println("ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 : "+ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180);
                    System.out.println("ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 : "+ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270);

                    if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) rotationAngle = 90;
                    if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) rotationAngle = 180;
                    if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) rotationAngle = 270;
                    System.out.println("Rotation Angle is : "+rotationAngle);
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                   // matrix.setRotate(rotationAngle, (float) photo.getWidth() / 2, (float) photo.getHeight() / 2);
                    matrix.postRotate(rotationAngle);

                    Bitmap rotatedBitmap=null;
                    try {
                        rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo, 0, 0, photo.getWidth(), photo.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: cameraimagename = path of the image(String) and Photo is the bitmap object generated previously

Comment: I tried similar code, it has been very slow to me, do you experience the same problem?

Comment: No @Helin Wang Its Perfectly Working on My Galaxy S2 Device

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to detect the image orientation and replace the bitmap using:

```
 /**
 * Rotate an image if required.
 * @param img
 * @param selectedImage
 * @return 
 */
private static Bitmap rotateImageIfRequired(Context context,Bitmap img, Uri selectedImage) {

    // Detect rotation
    int rotation=getRotation(context, selectedImage);
    if(rotation!=0){
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotation);
        Bitmap rotatedImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        img.recycle();
        return rotatedImg;        
    }else{
        return img;
    }
}

/**
 * Get the rotation of the last image added.
 * @param context
 * @param selectedImage
 * @return
 */
private static int getRotation(Context context,Uri selectedImage) {
    int rotation =0;
    ContentResolver content = context.getContentResolver();


    Cursor mediaCursor = content.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { "orientation", "date_added" },null, null,"date_added desc");

    if (mediaCursor != null && mediaCursor.getCount() !=0 ) {
        while(mediaCursor.moveToNext()){
            rotation = mediaCursor.getInt(0);
            break;
        }
    }
    mediaCursor.close();
    return rotation;
}
```

To avoid Out of memories with big images, I'd recommend you to rescale the image using:

```
private static final int MAX_HEIGHT = 1024;
private static final int MAX_WIDTH = 1024;
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap(Context context, Uri selectedImage)
        throws IOException {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    InputStream imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);
    imageStream.close();

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);

    img= rotateImageIfRequired(img, selectedImage);
    return img;
}
```

It's not posible to use ExifInterface to get the orientation because an Android OS issue: 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19268